# What is wrong with my code? I am stuck. I am trying to export some promise results

Tags: javascript, promise, export, undefined

I am trying to export an object to another module which includes a promise. I want results of the promises. I can get the result of promises, I just can't export. Or maybe I did everything wrong in this function.

I am building an application for people to create their own interactive stories.
I get a link, a heading, a story beginning, some story choices and story parts.
I was able to store them and sort them. I've cloned the original arrays, so I could modify the code safely.
Those clone arrays are the results of promises which are taken from the local storage. I've turned local storage functions to async functions so there is no problem about that.
The promises were ready and I've created this final function where I stuck.

```
export const sendToHell = {
  res: [],
  kamino: async function () {
    this.res = await Promise.all([
      stored.storedLink,
      stored.storedHeading,
      stored.storedBeginning,
      stored.storedChoices,
      stored.storedParts,
    ]);
    return this.res;
  },
  cloneLink: [...sendToHell.res[0]],
  cloneHeading: [...sendToHell.res[1]],
  cloneBeginning: [...sendToHell.res[2]],
  cloneChoices: [...sendToHell.res[3]],
  cloneParts: [...sendToHell.res[4]],
};

sendToHell.kamino();
```

The error I am getting here is 'Cannot access sendToHell beofre init.' What I actually need from this code is, modified clone arrays. When I used "this" key word. I get an another error. which is 'Cannot read properties of undefined reading res'

I've tried top level await but for a reason I don't know it doesn't work. "I know top level await only works in modules."
To be more clear.
"Stored" is an array which includes other arrays like stored link, stored heading...
"StoredHeading", "StoredBeginning"... Those are arrays coming from local storage. They are resolved promises.
"CloneHeading", "CloneBeginning" ... These will be the arrays which will be clones of Stored arrays and exported to another module.

Finally I know that exports and imports are synchronous. And if I write them in global scope they will be executed first while my promise is waiting. I've also tried the immediately executed function.
Thank you for your time.
Thank you for your time .

Comment: I think the problem is that `sendToHell` is not a class. You cannot use `this` in an object literal to refer to the object itself, since it doesn't work like an instantiated class.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and help. I am still working on it. Making sendToHell a class didn't solve my propblem but maybe it is because of some other mistake I made. When I am sure I made nothing wrong while building the class and calling it. I will edit the question. Much appreciated, thank you again.

Comment: You are providing three versions of code, and seem to ask questions on all of them. That is too broad. Just provide the code you have (one) problem with and focus on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sendToHell` is an anti-pattern of `Promise.all` -

```js
const [
  cloneLink,                     // <Value 1>
  cloneHeading,                  // <Value 2>
  cloneBeginning,                // <Value 3>
  cloneChoices,                  // <Value 4>
  cloneParts,                    // <Value 5>
] = await Promise.all([
  stored.storedLink,             // <Promise 1>
  stored.storedHeading,          // <Promise 2>
  stored.storedBeginning,        // <Promise 3>
  stored.storedChoices,          // <Promise 4>
  stored.storedParts,            // <Promise 5>
])
```

If you insist on a wrapper function -

```js
function kamino(stored) {
  return Promise.all([
    stored.storedLink,           // <Promise 1>
    stored.storedHeading,        // <Promise 2>
    stored.storedBeginning,      // <Promise 3>
    stored.storedChoices,        // <Promise 4>
    stored.storedParts,          // <Promise 5>
  ])
}

export { kamino }
```

```js
import { kamino } from "./path/to/kamino.js"

const [
  cloneLink,                     // <Value 1>
  cloneHeading,                  // <Value 2>
  cloneBeginning,                // <Value 3>
  cloneChoices,                  // <Value 4>
  cloneParts,                    // <Value 5>
] = await kamino(stored)
```

Comment: Thanks. This made me understand, I have a lot to learn and improve my thinking method.

Comment: Happy to assist :D

Answer (score -1):

Well, your code seems more/less correct. I am not certain what "store" variable holds, and not sure the purpose of your "sendToHell" object, however if it's possible It seems you would like to use "OOP" approach, which JavaScript is capable of since ES6 if I remember courtly. There are also closures which I am going to use in my example.

In lame terms what you want to do, is to create another async function that is awaiting your `kamino` function to resolve everything. If you are able to use top-level await I would suggest using this approach, I am going to create another function for that purpose.

```js
const sendToHell = (function () {
  let res = [];

  return {
    kamino: async function () {
      res = await Promise.all([
        "stored.storedLink",
        "stored.storedHeading",
        "stored.storedBeginning",
        "stored.storedChoices",
        "stored.storedParts"
      ]);
    },
    cloneLink: function () {
      return res[0];
    },
    cloneHeading: function () {
      return res[1];
    },
    cloneBeginning: function () {
      return res[2];
    },
    cloneChoices: function () {
      return res[3];
    },
    cloneParts: function () {
      return res[4];
    }
  };
})();

const initializeApp = async function () {
  const outputEl = document.getElementById("output");
  await sendToHell.kamino();
  // Change your function name for different output
  outputEl.innerHTML = sendToHell.cloneHeading();
};

initializeApp();
```

```html
<h1 id="output"></h1>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am going to edit my question. I've just realized the missing parts. Also this answer gave me another idea to create my application.

Comment: I've been doing some modifications and I believe I will solve this problem. Really appreciated. Thank you again. I am accepting this answer as accepted because it solves the main problem I made. I've should have created a second async function to solve the first one.

Comment: this is a dangerous api. `async` functions should _resolve_ a value (not set state like `res = ...`) which we can assign on the left side of `await`. see my answer for details.